# Substitute for ground crayfish?

Tags: condiments, crawfish

I love crayfish flavor, and love to add ground crayfish to most sauces and stews.  However I now live in an area where this condiment is scarce to unavailable.  What other seasoning or condiment can I use for a crayfish-like flavor?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I edited your title to make it more clear that you're asking about *ground* crayfish, which I think a lot of people won't have seen before.

Comment: Are you looking for the shellfish flavor or something more funky like you'd find in dried seafood? If the latter is your choice I'd suggest something like Thai fish sauce or even taking shrimp shells and roasting them in the oven and grinding them in a coffee grinder into a powder.

Answer (score 5):

You might give shrimp-based things a shot. If you have any kind of Asian grocery store around, you can probably find dried shrimp, shrimp paste, or even shrimp powder or bullion. You might find some of these things in Mexican grocery stores too, and shrimp broth-related stuff is sometimes sold in Western grocery stores too.

You could also try other seafood-based condiments. For example, furikake comes in a lot of varieties, including some with shrimp (ebi) or fish (bonito). There are likely to be some Asian liquid sauces that you'd like too, though I'm not sure what to specifically recommend there.